# Why is $\mathcal{M}^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ complete under $\| \cdot \|_{a,b}^{2}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, stochastic-processes, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

So I am reading, the Xuerong Mao book about Brownian Motion and Stochastic Integrals, and I came up to this definition

> Let $0\leq a < b <\infty$. Denote by $\mathcal{M}^2([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ the space of all real-valued measurable $\{F_t\}$-adapted processes $f=\{f(t)\}_{a\leq t \leq b}$ such that $$ \vert\vert f\vert\vert_{a,b}^2=E\int_a^b \vert f(t)\vert^2dt<\infty.$$
> We identify $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ in $\mathcal{M}^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ if $\| f-\tilde{f}\|t_{a,b}^2=0$. In this case we say that $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ are equivalent and write $f=\tilde{f}$.

After this, they say that $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_{a,b}^2$ is a metric on $\mathcal{M}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ and the space is complete. However I think that there is a bit of problems with the notation (and I wanted to verify). It could work if we were working with a norm, however since metrics should be maps $\mathcal{M}^2([a,b], \mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{M}^2([a,b], \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ then, to prove it is a metric we would take $f_1$ and $f_2$ and then define their distance by $\| f_1-f_2\|_{a,b}^2$.

Then, heuristically,  all the properties of a metric (symmetric, triangle inequality, and non-negativity) would follow by the properties of the absolute value, monotonicity and linearity of the integral and $E$. In particular, the non-negativity would come from the equivalence given in the definition. Am I wrong, or should I work with it as a norm?

Also, besides the fact that the integrals are finite and so if we have a Cauchy secuence we can change integral with the limit and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_{1n}(t)-f_{2n}(t)=0$, I haven't come up with other arguments to show that the space is complete. So any formal arguments or corrections will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but every normed space is a metric space with the induced metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. What do you mean "work with it as a norm"?

Comment: As to whether call $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_{a,b}^2$ a norm or a metric. In particular, because I see problems trying to prove $\vert \vert cf(t) \vert \vert = \vert c\vert \; \vert \vert f(t) \vert\vert$ if it were a norm. However if I called it a metric then I wouldn't have the map $\mathcal{M}^2([a,b],R) \times \mathcal{M}^2([a,b],R) \to R$, just $ \mathcal{M}^2([a,b],R) \to R$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If$$ \vert\vert f\vert\vert_{a,b}^2=E\int_a^b \vert f(t)\vert^2dt<\infty$$Then$$\begin{align*} \vert\vert cf\vert\vert_{a,b}^2 &=E\int_a^b \vert cf(t)\vert^2dt \\ &=|c|^2E\int_a^b \vert f(t)\vert^2dt \\ &= |c|^2\vert\vert f\vert\vert_{a,b}^2\end{align*}$$

Comment: Exactly, then it wouldn't be a norm since you get the constant squared, not just the asbsolute value.

Comment: But you take the square root of both sides: $\|cf\| = |c|\|f\|$

Comment: my bad, I thought the $2$ was because of the space, not an actual power.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the space, but that would be very bad notation. I suspect that the 2 in $\mathcal{M}^2$ represents "square integrable".

Comment: What you need to prove is that $\| f\|_{a, b}$ is a norm. This is obvious if you have some measure theory under you since $\|f\|_{a,b}^2$ is the $\mathscr{L}^2$-norm on the product space $\Omega \times [a, b]$ with measures $\mathbf{P}$ and $\lambda$ (the probability measure on $\Omega$ and the Lebesgue measure on $[a, b]$).

Comment: But then, why would the space be complete?

Comment: The completeness is not obvious, but proofs have been around for awhile.  Any good graduate analysis textbook should have a proof of the completeness of the $L^p$ spaces.  Maybe these notes give you what you want http://www2.math.uu.se/~rosko894/teaching/Part_03_Lp%20spaces_ver_1.0.pdf